# FTP error on Quit command

Tags: ftp, command, quit

I'm using a ftp library that causes an error sending the quit command. It seems that the character before QUIT is not recognized. I took a look at the code but didn't find anything.

500 '?QUIT': command not understood

Does anyone know what this character can be?

Comment: What language? A code sample would be helpful. As a shot in the dark, what encoding are your strings in? Should be ascii for FTP afaik.

Also, try throwing wireshark on the connection and see what you're actually sending. It can be quite valuable.

Comment: Need more info about the library you're using, under which language/runtime, sample code etc

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use a network sniffer to monitor the traffic over the FTP port (21) and check what is the actual character (typically in Hex format).